# Question about the way how 'apply method' runs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I read documents which explain about `apply` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply )

Although i read this whole document, I still don't understand the way how `apply` method runs

For example,

```
const string_array = ['a', 'b'];
const number_array = [0, 1, 2];
string_array.push.apply(string_array, number_array);
console.info(string_array); // ["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]
```

After calling `string_array.push.apply`, Why `string_array` returns `["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]`?

Is that just a rule?. There is no reason???

Because `string_array` is a `Array` so, when `string_array` pushes `number_array`

Return value should be `["a", "b", [0, 1, 2] ]`

I don't think the method of `push` work properly, when returns value is like `["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]`.

that is `concat`

Can anybody explain these why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
string_array.push(0, 1, 2);
```

...the `push` method receives this information *(ignoring some details)*:

- `this = string_array`, because when you call a function as part of a property access (`string_array.push`), JavaScript is defined such that `this` within the function call is the object you looked up the property on.
- The arguments `0`, `1`, and `2`, because you listed them explicitly when calling `push`.

When you do this:

```
string_array.push.apply(string_array, number_array)
```

you're specifying those same two pieces of information (what `this` is and what the arguments are), but you're doing it explicitly via the arguments to `apply`. The value for `this` is the first argument to `apply`, and the list of arguments is the second argument to `apply`, given as an array or array-like object (something with a `length` property and properties with number-like names).

That's really it. Either way, direct call or via `apply`, the JavaScript engine calls the `push` method with `this` set to `string_array` and the arguments `0`, `1`, and `2`.

> Why `string_array.push.apply(string_array, number_array)`; returns `["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]`?

It doesn't, it returns `5`. The return value of `push` is the new length of the array. But after that call, `string_array` contains those entries, yes.

> Return value should be `["a", "b", [0, 1, 2] ]`

No, that's simply not how `push` and `apply` are defined. `apply` takes the array/array-like object you pass it and gives its entries to the function you call as discrete arguments.

If you'd done `call`, *then* `string_array` would end up with `["a", "b", [0, 1, 2] ]`:

```js
const string_array = ['a', 'b'];
const number_array = [0, 1, 2];
string_array.push.call(string_array, number_array);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
console.info(string_array); // ["a", "b", [0, 1, 2]]
```

That's because `call` is defined differently from `apply`. Instead of accepting the arguments for the call as an array or array-like object, `call` accepts them as discrete parameters (like `push` does). So this:

```
string_array.push.call(string_array, number_array);
```

is equivalent to:

```
string_array.push(number_array);
```

Comment: I edited about `Why string_array.push.apply(string_array, number_array); returns ["a", "b", 0, 1, 2]?`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much, For now, i fully understood how `apply` method runs.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you expect would work for `Array.push()`, not Array.prototype.push.apply();

```
a = [1,2];
b = [3,4,5];
a.push(b);
console.log(a); // [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]];
```

`a.push.apply(a,b);` [takes arguments as array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), and takes the elements of one array and putting it in the other.

`a.concat(b);` returns new array and does not change a or b.